# what is the maximum value that can be assigned to rununtildate for runloop?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsrunloop

I am trying to make this runloop run forever(if not forever atleast for a single day) I am using the following function for runloop `[self.runLoop runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:100000]];`

The problem is that the app crashes after 3 hours.Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you give us some more information about the crash?

Comment: @gaige the app just stops working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to run perpetually (and assuming you've attached timers and/or input sources), you can use

```
[self.runLoop run];
```

If you want to stay with your current construct, you can use:

```
[self.runLoop runUntilDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
```

I've seen Apple use the following pattern (e.g. listing 3-14 of the [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-131281); I've also seen `NSOperation` objects use this construct when invoking an asynchronous operation that they want to wait to complete):

```
// Let the run loop process things.
do
{
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                             beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
while ( ... ); // in here you have whatever condition you want to check for
```

Comment: why do i need a while block? I dont need to check any condition.I want the run loop to run forever.How do i add your infor to my line of code?

Comment: @iOsBoy If you want it to run forever, you can just invoke `run` or `runUntilDate:[NSDate distantFuture]` (assuming you've attached a timer and/or input source). The while loop and `runMode` construct is useful if you're going to terminate upon some condition. Obviously you could use `while(TRUE)`, but the other constructs probably make more sense at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Try `[NSDate distantFuture]`. From the documentation: "An NSDate object representing a date in the distant future (in terms of centuries)."